# Is there any limit for number of Triggers in UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using UpdatePanel in ASP.NET application. Is there any limit for number of triggers for a  UpdatePanel?

Is there any performance constraint if there are more triggers for a UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't ever read of a constraint.  Performance is not only based on triggers, but page size, number of controls, etc.  To my knowledge, there has not been any specific testing to determine the limits of this.

However, you also have to factor in maintainability, and whether that would be easy to manage and debug problems for.

Comment: What i thought is using triggers keeps everything under our control and can avoid undesired Partial Page refresh.

Comment: Triggers cause a partial page refresh; it always refreshes, along with the entire viewstate.  It really doesn't necessarily save much on performance.  While many triggers may perform OK, the amount of data going over the wire will still be rather large because of the viewstate.

Comment: Thank You Brian for your insights. I will be looking into the Performance part and keep you posted. :)